# Let $R$ be a euclidean domain, with norm function $N: R^{*} \to N$.

Tags: ring-theory, euclidean-domain

Show that $a, b \in R^*, N(a) = N(ab)$ if, and only if, $a$ and $b$ are associate.

I tried to solve this using the fact that if $N(a) = N(ab)$ then $a \in <ab>.$ But I failed.
 Any Help?

Comment: Do you mean $N(a)=N(b)$ if and only if $a$ and $b$ are associates?

Comment: No. What I got here is exactly this: $N(a) = N(ab)$ if and only if $a$ and $b$ are associates.

Comment: If $b$ is a unit, $N(ab)=N(a)$, otherwise $N(ab)>N(a)$.  Your statement as written just isn't true.  Think about $\Bbb{Z}$ with $N(n)=|n|$.  Then $2$ and $-2$ are associates but certainly $|2|\neq |2(-2)|$

Comment: Wait I see, you're saying $a, b \in R^{\times}$

Comment: Wait, I'am not sure if $a$ and $b$ can not be a unit. This statement is not true even if $a$ and $b$ are not units?

Comment: Unless $b$ is a unit, $N(ab)=N(a)$ is false.

Comment: @sharding4 I think that $R^*$ means the set of nonzero elements of $R$. In that case, the statement given by the OP is false as you've shown.